# elasticsearch read timeout, seems to have too many shards?

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm using both elasticsearch 1.4.4/2.1.0 with cluster of 5 hosts on AWS. In the config file, I've set index shard num to 10.

So here comes the strange behavior: I created a index everyday, and when there's about 400 shards or more, the whole cluster returns Read Timeout when using Buik index API.
If I delete some indices, the timeout error disappeared.

Anyone meets similar problem? This is really a big obstacle for storing more data

Comment: you create indexes everyday thats fine ...but why do you bulk index?

Comment: I mean, bulk insert. sorry my bad

Comment: OK, so you make indexes daily imagine on 2015-Dec-1 you created index A.2015-Dec-2 you created index B. 2015-Dec-3 you created index C...so on
I am imagining all of them have same mapping. Now today you create index D and you bulk insert in D. Then i am surprised how come deleting indices help you. Are you doing anything other than what i am saying if so please update it in teh question.

Comment: well, exactly as you said, the mappings are the same. So today I'm writing data into indexD but failed, then delete indexA helps the the cluster recovered. So I've had a cron job which deletes indices created 10 days ago to keep the cluster running. I'm sure I've done nothing else, pretty weird.

Comment: Are you creating an alias for all the index and then bulk inserting it into the index via alias?

Comment: no, i'm using the name like "metric-2015.12.14" which is auto created by the   mapping template